# SRST failed (errno = -16) while resuming from suspend

Tags: hard-drive, suspend

I see this error briefly at the top of a full screen console-type text screen as the computer restarts from suspend.  At the start of the message is something about ATA, so I think it's to do with a hard disk restarting and something failing.

Should I worry?  Everything seems to be working.

Edit:  Smart status on the 2 disk drives is green, although one has a few bad sectors. I will watch it more closely.

Answer (score 0):

This has not been answered in 5 years and I doubt you are still stuck but I will write this in case others have this problem.

I have had this problem before and it is usually caused by a loose (or bad) cable between the hard drive and the motherboard.

The first attempt to solve the problem should be to disconnect and reattach both ends of all the hard drive cables. If the "SRST failed" message continues then replace the cables with new cables. If that does not work, it could be the connector on the drive or the mainboard.